# React redux + react-loadable... How to make it work?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-loadable

I'm working in a react app and I'm using `react-loadable` and `react-redux`. When I started the project, I did not use `react-redux` and the Loadable component worked perfect. But now I want to use redux (I'm learning...) and I can not get it to work :(

I do not know what I have to do.

Thanks! (:

---

Error

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTAov.png)

---

**index.js**

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9'; // For IE 9-11 support
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11'; // For IE 11 support
import './polyfill'
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import './index.css';
import {store} from './helpers';
import {App} from "./views/App";


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

---

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {HashRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

import '../../App.scss';
import {history} from '../../helpers';
import LoadingSpinner from '../../components/Loading/LoadingSpinner';
import PrivateRoute from '../../components/PrivateRoute';
import {alertActions} from '../../actions/alert_actions';
// import {Login} from "../Pages/Login";

const loading = () => <LoadingSpinner/>;

const Login = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('../../views/Pages/Login')
    .then(state => {
      const {store} = this.props;
    }),
  loading
});

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }


  render() {
    const {alert} = this.props;
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" component={Login}/>
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const {alert} = state;
  return {
    alert,
  };
}

const connectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
export {connectedApp as App};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use your Login page component with redux and react-loadable, you have to import the Login page component container which is connected to the Redux store via connect() function. For example, your container would look something like this,

**login.container.js**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Login } from '../../views/Pages/Login'

const mapStateToProps = ...

const mapDispatchToProps = ...

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Login)
```

and then in order to lazy load it, you just have to import the previous file, instead of the component as the loader key.

**App.js**

```
...
const loading = () => <LoadingSpinner/>;

const Login = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./login.container.ts'),
  loading
});
...
```

Now the component should work as expected with Redux.